# Donut Chart Plugin with jQuery And D3.js need help in event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, donut-chart

I am using donut pie chart in my project and needed to find out more events; for eg:

1. legend,
2. data display format,
3. Calculating given values into chart percentage.

Found ref from [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Dynamic-Donut-Pie-Chart-Plugin-with-jQuery-D3-js-donut-pie-chart-js.html)

Passing data like below:

```
$("#piechart").donutpie();
var chart_data = [
    {"name":"Fruits","hvalue":40.54,color:"#E33244"},
    {"name":"Veggies","hvalue":30.23,color:"#F89406"},
    {"name":"Bakery","hvalue":50,color:"#82AF6F"}
]
$("#piechart").donutpie('update', chart_data);
```

Below is the result

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things in it, I solved it as below :

1. set manually designed legends
2. data display and calculation handled manually
3. To display float value in chart, made necessary changes into main package file.